# Project Fi SMS_RECEIVED

Tags: android, sms

The standard SMS_RECEIVED intent and the Google Voice SMS_RECEIVED both does not work for the phones with Google's "Project Fi" as carrier and Hangouts enabled for SMS. Is there a way to receive the SMS received message in these conditions?

Comment: What do you have the Receiver's priority set at?

Comment: Priority is set as 999 and I have tried targetVersion both as 18 and above.